# Don't show individual case study if the WordPress page ID = the case study ID

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to pull in/select a different case study to show if the page ID = the case study ID. The reason for this is that currently I've a content block at the bottom of my individual case studies to read other case studies I written. With this though I'm currently being recommend the same case study as the case study page I'm currently on due to it being the latest case study published. You can view this below: [image]

As you can see in the img I'm on the muck truck case study and still being recommended it again in the "Other Case Study" section to the page. I want to exclude the muck truck case study being pulled into the "Other Case Study" section while on the individual case study page. The same goes for if I was on one of the other individual case studies page.

```
<div class='col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1'>

    <?php $case_study_posts = array(
        'post_type' => 'case_study',
        'showposts' => 2
    );
    $case_study = new WP_Query( $case_study_posts );

    if ( $case_study->have_posts() ) : while ( $case_study->have_posts() ) : $case_study->the_post(); ?>

        <?php $case_study_id = get_the_ID(); ?>

        <?php if($page_id = $case_study_id): ?>

            <article class="col-sm-6">

                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><img src="<?php the_field('case_study_featured_img'); ?>" alt="" /></a>
                <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_field('case_study_heading'); ?></a></h3>
                <?php the_field('case_study_excerpt'); ?>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><button class="btn btn-dark">Read Case Study</button></a>

            </article>

        <?php endif; ?>

    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>

</div>
```

Comment: you can add `"post__not_in" => get_the_ID,` in the array for Wp_Query

Answer (score 0):

```
'post__not_in' => array (get_the_ID()),
```

Comment: Please provide more than just code as an answer. Instead, an explanation of the code and a breakdown of why it would work to answer the question is most beneficial.